# Resource xml/opener_paths (aka io.ionic.starter:xml/opener_paths) not found

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic4, ionic-native

Getting error while android build

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider;${applicationId}.bugshaker.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" ></meta-data>
        </provider>
```

Error message is:

> android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:39:13-41:65: AAPT: error: resource xml/opener_paths (aka io.ionic.starter:xml/opener_paths) not found.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same error. This is what worked for me:

I went to the root project directory in a command prompt and run:

```
ionic cap sync
```

Then, it gave me another error in

```
android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\io\github\pwlin\cordova\plugins\fileopener2
```

I had to change

```
public class FileProvider extends android.support.v4.content.FileProvider
```

to

```
public class FileProvider extends androidx.core.content.FileProvider
```

Now I'm able to run the project in an Android device

Comment: This is because I was using Capacitor, if you are using Cordova, I guess instead of ```ionic cap sync``` you should remove the android platform and then add it again

Comment: With Capacitor, this is the solution. Changing android.support.v4 to androidx.core is required after every cap sync or rebuild, the same applies to Camera plugin.